# wm.context_toggle for Toggle On / Off X-RAY Armature ( Context attribute )

Tags: shortcut

hi im looking for correct context attribute to toggle on / off with shortcut key at input editor
XRAY armature because i find use it often and decided to make it as shortcut

[image]

i tried the following context attribute but gives error

1. active_object.data.show_x_ray
2. Object.Show_x_ray

thank you for answers

Comment: Have you tried `object.show_x_ray` without the caps? Python is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your custom keyboard shortcut like this:

[image: Custom keyboard shortcut for toggling X-ray display]

### Key points

- When setting toggle shortcuts use `wm.context_toggle`
- When it pertains to the active object use `active_object.` followed by the last part of your context attribute name, which in this case is `show_x_ray`
- If you add this to the list under the **Object Mode** section the shortcut will only trigger X-ray display while you are in Object Mode, which frees up your keyboard shortcut to be used for something else in Edit Mode, etc. If you add it under **3D View (Global)** the keyboard shortcut will trigger it in *all* 3D View modes.

Answer (score 0):

Close with Object.  Without getting too technical you will not find a data_path containing capitals.
Any one of

```
bpy.ops.wm.context_toggle(data_path="object.show_x_ray")
bpy.ops.wm.context_toggle(data_path="active_object.show_x_ray")
bpy.ops.wm.context_toggle(data_path="scene.objects.active.show_x_ray")
```

The python console C is a shortcut for bpy.context, and [ctrl-space] is autocomplete.  With the armature selected, typing C.ob[ctrl-space] completes to C.object.  Add a . and  again gives you the list of properties.